# Is there any way generalise program specific seting in vs code?

Tags: c, gcc, pow, math.h

I was working with pow() function in c using vscode.
And I want to use a variable in exponent parameter of power function i.e. pow (2, i).
But i was getting error so, I used gcc programName.c -lm during compilation in terminal.
Is there any way by which I can use normal compilation command  like gcc programName.c and get output of program with same problem.

```
n = 10;
h = 0;
while (n > pow(2, h))
   h++;
printf("\n%d\n", h);
```

error:
/tmp/ccptU1ZR.o: In function `main':
BinaryTree.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to`pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

expected output : 
4

Comment: Using `pow` for calculation of integer powers of `2` is an overkill. Have you heard of bit shifting?

Comment: nope can you please enlighten me....?

Comment: `2^n` is the same as shifting the number `1` n binary positions left. Or `1 << n` in C. There are some limitations of course, but this will give you a kickstart.

Comment: oh gotcha..... But what about base other than 2.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-lm` option is not a different type of compilation, rather it is telling the compiler (actually the linker) where to find the meaning or definition of the `pow()` function. So use `-lm` with no worries, all it says is that there are math functions in the code otherwise gcc will not bother looking on its own.